# Inverse Laplace transform of the hypergeometric function 2F1

Tags: special-functions, laplace-transform

In the book Integrals and Series: Inverse Laplace Transforms by A.P. Prudnikov, the inverse Laplace transform of the hypergeometric function 2F1 defined as

$$
_{2}F_{1}(p+a,b;c;-\omega), \qquad [b,p+a\neq 0,-1,-2,\ldots;\omega,Re\;b, Re(c-b)>0 ]
$$

is given as

$$
\Gamma\left[\begin{matrix} c \\ b,c-b \\ \end{matrix}\right]\omega^{1-c}e^{(1-a)x}\times(e^x-1)^{b-1}(1+\omega-e^x)^{c-b-1}_{+}
$$

Now my question is how can I obtain this inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: I assume you mean $\mathcal{L}_p^{-1}[\, _2F_1(a+p,b;c;-\omega)](x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int\limits_{\beta-i \infty}^{\beta+i \infty} \, _2F_1(a+p,b;c;-\omega)\, e^{x p}\,dp$. What is the meaning of the $+$ subscript on the end of your result formula?

Comment: I replicated exactly what is in the book. About the plus sign, it probably means the inverse exists just for positive values.

Comment: My main point with the formula was the integration variable seems to be $p$ (versus $\omega$). Can you please give a reference for the meaning of the notation $\Gamma\left[\begin{matrix} c \\ b,c-b \\ \end{matrix}\right]$?

Comment: Perhaps you also need to clarify whether you're asking about the inverse unilateral or bilateral Laplace transform.